# I have a array of dictionaries, how to implement a binary search based on the values in the dictionaries?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an array of dictionaries, like this

```
myDicArray = [[
               "id": "105",
               "b": "apple",
               "c": "red",
              ],
              [
               "id": "409",
               "b": "pear",
               "c": "yellow",
              ],
              [
               "id": "769",
               "b": "orange",
               "c": "orange",
              ]]
```

I was wondering is there a way to do a binary search based on the value of "id", and retrieve the corresponding dictionary?

For example, if I take input 409, can I do a binary search on [105, 409, 769] and the output should be;

```
          [
           "id": "409",
           "b": "pear",
           "c": "yellow",
          ]
```

I found a method from GitHub to implement binary search on an array;

```
 func binarySearch<T: Comparable>(_ a: [T], key: T) -> Int? {
    var lowerBound = 0
    var upperBound = a.count
    while lowerBound < upperBound {
        let midIndex = lowerBound + (upperBound - lowerBound) / 2
        if a[midIndex] == key {
            return midIndex
        } else if a[midIndex] < key {
            lowerBound = midIndex + 1
        } else {
            upperBound = midIndex
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

But I am confused about how to implement it on an array of dictionaries?

Really appreciate any help, many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have slightly edited the `binarySearch` function to allow you to search for a value of type `T` in an array of type `[U]`, provided a function that maps `(U) -> T`:

```
func binarySearch<T: Comparable, U>(_ a: [U], key: T, keyMapper: (U) -> T) -> U? {
    var lowerBound = 0
    var upperBound = a.count
    while lowerBound < upperBound {
        let midIndex = lowerBound + (upperBound - lowerBound) / 2
        if keyMapper(a[midIndex]) == key {
            return a[midIndex]
        } else if keyMapper(a[midIndex]) < key {
            lowerBound = midIndex + 1
        } else {
            upperBound = midIndex
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Usage:

```
binarySearch(myDicArray, key: "769") { $0["id"]! }
```

Note that the IDs in your dictionaries are *strings*, not numbers, please ensure that they are sorted *lexicographically*, instead of numerically.

Also, you could consider creating a struct for your data, and using a `[MyStruct]` to store them instead:

```
struct MyStruct {
    let id: String
    let b: String
    let c: String
}

let myStructArray = [
    MyStruct(id: "105", a: "apple", b: "red"),
    ...
]
```

Comment: Thanks soooo much! I was wondering is it better to use struct to store those data rather than plist? Actually I have more than two hundred thousand entries, my system have a performance issue after applying binary search on plist.It takes 7 second to get the info. I was wondering do you have any suggestions on how to improve the performance time-wise? Is it better to use a database like sqlite?

Comment: @HermioneC if you have that many, you probably  should store the data in a plist or json, then read it as an array of struct. Alternatively consider a database.